# Run babel plugin before syntax check

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have custom babel plugin which works in a way that using it introduces syntax errors. However after a plugin would be applied the syntax errors would not be there. But i get syntax error sooner than it reaches the plugin. The plugin should go through code and remove the code that would turn to an error. The error is about redefining identifier.

The transpiled code is e.g.

```js
import something from "moduleA";
import something from "moduleB";
```

In my custom plugin I want to decide which import should be used and remove second one by `path.remove()`. That would leave only one `something` identifier. But I get an error during transpilation:

```
SyntaxError: C:\filepath\file.js: Identifier 'something' has already been declared
```

How can I run the plugin before syntax check? Or maybe can I suppress the error?

Comment: I usually see the error throwing at either during transforming process or runtime level. It's unclear as saying syntax check here. It would be better if you share more details here.

Comment: The error is during transform process and stops the process.

Comment: If so, you might have to check the order in the `plugins` configuration for example put you plugin on the top of the list to make sure your plugin will go first.

Comment: which module throw this error anyway?